# Bass- Serre theory exercise

Tags: gr.group-theory

I read the paper "Kurosh rank of intersections of subgroups of free products of orderable groups", which can be found here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.0233.
The proposition 2.3 states that: Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Let $T'$ be a $H$-subtree of $T$. Then $κ_{T}(H)$ = $κ_{T′}(H)$.
In particular, $T_{H}/H$ is ﬁnite (as a graph) if and only if $κ_T(H)$ is ﬁnite.

They leave it as Bass-Serre exercise.
I am not very good in Bass-Serre theory, so I would appreciate if anyone can help me with this proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need that every vertex of $T$ whose $H$-stabilizer is nontrivial is contained in the $H$-minimal subtree $T_H \subset T$, and so each such vertex is contained in $T'$. This implies that $c_T(H)=c_{T'}(H)$ where $c$ is the number of orbits of vertices with nontrivial stabilizer.

Next you need that the equivariant deformation retraction from $T$ to $T'$ descends to a deformation retraction from $T/H$ to $T'/H$, which again is a consequence of the fact that vertices not in $T_H$ have trivial stabilizers. It follows that $rank(T/H)=rank(T'/H)$ where $rank$ means the rank of the first homology group of a graph.

So $\kappa_{T}(H)=c_T(H)+rank(T/H)=c_{T'}(H)+rank(T'/H)=\kappa_{T'}(H)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it is very helpful for me.